# Roku Streaming Channel from Kit Digital

Tags: streaming, live, roku

I've been developing a roku channel mostly from the tutorials found on http://www.herofish.com/2012/01/how-to-create-you-own-roku-videoplayer-channel/ and it's been coming together well. Now my issue is that I am trying to connect the channel to a Kit Digital Live stream (a .m3u8 stream) and I don't know how to connect the channel to that stream instead of a regular pick your video stream.

Does anyone know where I can find instructions on how to do this or documentation that could help? (I've already looked through the developer guide and forum but can't find any clues)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the demo code in: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rokusdkexamples/files/customvideoplayer.zip/download  shows you how to use HLS and some other cool playback features.

```
this.player.SetMessagePort(this.port)
this.player.SetLoop(true)
this.player.SetPositionNotificationPeriod(1)
this.player.SetDestinationRect(this.layout.left)
this.player.SetContentList([{
    Stream: { url: "http://ec2-184-72-239-149.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1935/demos/smil:bigbuckbunnyiphone.smil/playlist.m3u8" }
    StreamFormat: "hls"
    SwitchingStrategy: "full-adaptation"
}])
this.player.Play()
```

Comment: It actually worked. I really loved my Roku so far, but now I adore it!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest example for testing HLS streams is the simplevideoplayer example, on sourceforge or in your downloaded SDK. Simply find the "Big Buck Bunny" section, replace the url in quotes there with your .m3u8 url, add srt="" and then comment out the other examples.

```
' Big Buck Bunny test stream from Wowza
urls = ["http://myserver.com/mystream.m3u8"]
streamformat = "hls"
title = "Big Buck Bunny"
srt=""
```